# Facebook Debugger Shows Multiple Images (10+), but Posting Only Shows 3

Tags: facebook, drupal

When I try to share a page on Facebook I get the option of choosing between 3 thumbnails. Theoretically there should be closer to 20 because they are right there on the page.

When I look at the Facebook Debugger (linter) I see tons of images, but still, when I post I only get to choose between 3.

I would love to share the link, but as it's for a private client, I can not. Just curious if anyone has any theories.

Thanks!

Also, it's a Drupal site.

Comment: Facebook started limiting the amount of images they offer the user to chose from to a maximum of three quite a while ago.

Comment: I did not realize that. Thanks. Figures FB would choose the worst 3 they possibly could from my home page. I'll have to work out some og tags. Clearly.